# Combine few Expression<Func<T,bool>

Tags: c#, expression, azure-table-storage

I have 5 Expression<Func<T,bool> to filter data in Azure storage table. I need to combine all of them.

```
Expression<Func<T,bool>> x = (e => e.a < value))
Expression<Func<T,bool>> y = ...
Expression<Func<T,bool>> z = ...
Expression<Func<T,bool>> a = ...
Expression<Func<T,bool>> b =..
```

Expression in reality are complex, so writing one expression with lot of or,and will be difficult to read and understand. So I wrote 5 expression. Now I need to do something like this :

(b and ((x and y) or (z and a)))

I already did x and y, z and a in following way :

```
var XYcombined = Expression.And(Expression.Invoke(x,parameter), Expression.Invoke(y,parameter)
var ZAcombined = Expression.And(Expression.Invoke(z,parameter), Expression.Invoke(a,parameter)
var ORcombined = Expression.Or(XYcombined, ZAcombined)
```

now I need to somehow combine ORcombined with one more expression, I tried to use Expression.And and Expression.AndAlso, but azure returns http 500.

Comment: Have you tried to use Albahari's [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)?

Comment: Please post the exception message.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I just figured it out, it wasnt a problem with expressions, but with azure itself. One of expression use Select method on some collection. Azure doesnt support Select method in filters. So I removed this expression and I filter it after I get response from azure.